# Toggle the PHP session variable everytime the page is reloaded

Tags: php

I have a different requirement. I want to toggle the PHP SESSION variable value everytime the page is reloaded/refreshed.
Say, I have a variable

```
$_SESSION['id'] = 1;
```

When the page is loaded again, the value should be changed to 0. But when it should not happen when another page is opened.

Say my session variable is in page1. when page1 is again reloaded, the session variable should be changed. But when we go to page2 and come back to page1, it should be same as before. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use PHP sessions for this, assuming you want the variable to toggle per-user. If you consult the relevant section of the manual, you'll be able to find enough information to give it a go. If you can do that, and edit it into your question, I suspect people will vote to reopen. I didn't vote to close, but I suspect that's the reason for the down/close votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $_SESSION['var'] = empty($_SESSION['var']) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done in a variable. You need to use `sessions` for this.

Set the Session as `$_SESSION['id']`. Look at [Sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Answer (score 2):

The solutions depends on the level of interaction you want that "toggle" to happen.

If you want to achieve this toggle for every user on its own, you're good to go with sessions.

If you want to have the toggle application-wide (every user toggles one single value) you'll have to use any kind of persistence layer (e.g. a database, a file) to store the current state of you `$i` value in it.

Comment: Good point - it's hard to tell from the question which one is meant.